# Apache on Ubuntu / protected folder

Tags: apache2, ssl

I tried to long, hope you can help me.

I set up an apache server with one protected folder using the 000-default.conf (https://pastebin.com/hzvAv7fn)

Everything worked fine until I forced traffic to https:// Now, when I navigate to https://example.com/private it does not ask me for username/password anymore.

Can you help me please?

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that your definition of password access is inside the section for `<VirtualHost *:80>`.

This section *only* applies to things served over http. Effectively you have two sites; one http and one https site. They may be served out of the same folder, but from apache's view they're two distinct sites, with their own settings.

The solution is to add the `<Directory "/var/www/html/privat/">`-definition to the https sites configuration.

Comment: Thank you. May I ask: how would I add this to my https sites definition. Where donI find the file?

Comment: How did you add your https site? Have you had a look in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`?